# How to display information in another PHP Page

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I am having trouble with a mini shopping cart. I have created the mini shopping cart and when a product is added it goes into the Basket page. However, i want to create a checkout page. How do i grab the products in the basket and put it in a checkout page.

So For example, the check out page will look like this

ITEM NAME, ITEM MODEL, ITEM PRICE

```
                 TOTAL OF ITEMS
```

CHECKOUT BUTTON (links to a payment system)

This is my Basket.php code:

```
<?php
    $bikecode = $_GET['id'];     //the product id from the URL 
    $action = $_GET['action']; //the action from the URL

if($bikecode && !productExists($bikecode)) {
    die("Product Doesn't Exist");
} 

    switch($action) {   //decide what to do 

        case "add":
            $_SESSION['cart'][$bikecode]++; //add one to the quantity of the product with id $bikecode 
        break;

        case "remove":
            $_SESSION['cart'][$bikecode]--; //remove one from the quantity of the product with id $bikecode 
            if($_SESSION['cart'][$bikecode] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$bikecode]); //if the quantity is zero, remove it completely (using the 'unset' function) - otherwise is will show zero, then -1, -2 etc when the user keeps removing items. 
        break;

        case "empty":
            unset($_SESSION['cart']); //unset the whole cart, i.e. empty the cart. 
        break;
    }

    if($_SESSION['cart']){

        echo "<table width=\"100%\">";   

          foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $bikecode => $quantity) { 
             $sql = sprintf("SELECT BikeCode, Model, Price FROM Bike WHERE BikeCode = '%s';", $bikecode);

                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

                    list($bikecode, $model, $price) = mysqli_fetch_row($result);    

                    $cost = $quantity * $price;
                    $total = $total + $cost;

                        echo "<tr><th>BikeCode:</th><th>Model:</th><th>Quantity:</th><th>Price:</th></tr>";
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$bikecode</td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$model</td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">$quantity <a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=remove&id=$bikecode\">X</a></td>";
                        echo "<td align=\"center\">£$cost</td>";
                    echo "</tr>";
                }
            }

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan=\"3\" align=\"right\">Total</td>";
                echo "<td align=\"right\">£$total</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan=\"4\" align=\"right\"><a href=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]?action=empty\" onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\">Empty Cart</a></td>";
            echo "</tr>";       
        echo "</table>";

    }else{
        echo "You have no items in your shopping cart.";
    }

function productExists($bikecode) {
    $sql = sprintf("SELECT * FROM Bike WHERE BikeCode = '%s';", $bikecode); 
    return mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql)) > 0;
}
?>
```

Comment: if you're already using cookies why not just echo these variables into your checkout page?

Comment: I tried did not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you have a `session_start();` on top of every page you should be able to use the exact same foreach loop as you do in this piece of coding. The session with the information would just be carried over to the next page.

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have a page called test.php with the following code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['test'] = 1;
echo $_SESSION['test']; 
?>
```

Then to access the test variable in othertest.php page,simply do the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['test']; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `session_start()` to the top of your php file. I recommend adding `session_start()` to a separate file and then including that file in each of the php pages that uses session variables.